# How can I create a WP_Query that returns posts where one meta_value <= another meta_value

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I have a working, pretty complex SQL query hand-written in a function. For the sake of leveraging `WP_Query` optimizations, and simplifying my code for maintainability, I'd like to convert it all to using `WP_Query`. Most of it is obvious, but I have one `meta_value` thing in my `WHERE` that is a little non-standard and I don't know how to convert this part.

I need to select for posts where the meta_value in one `postmeta` row is `<=` the `meta_value` for another `postmeta` row.

Stripping away a lot of extraneous stuff, here is the hand-coded `SELECT` and `WHERE` stuff that is relevant:

```
$query = "
  SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts p
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta stock ON (p.ID = stock.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock')
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta threshold ON (p.ID = threshold.post_id AND threshold.meta_key = '_low_inventory_number')
";

$where .= "
  AND threshold.meta_value IS NOT NULL
  AND stock.meta_value IS NOT NULL
  AND CAST(threshold.meta_value AS SIGNED) != 0
  AND CAST(stock.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= CAST(threshold.meta_value AS SIGNED)
";
```

The very last line there where I am comparing the stock `meta_value` with the threshold `meta_value` is what I don't see how to convert into the use of a `meta_query` (AKA "Custom Field") array argument to `WP_query`.