# Filter posts by comparing custom meta value against postdate

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I have custom meta fields, `delivery_date` and `collection_date` on WooCommerce orders.

I actually have various fields with the same data, in various formats (`Y-m-d`; `U`; `D d/m/Y`) any of which may be useful.

I'd like to list (in an admin page; `is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()`) all *invalid* orders - those where the delivery date or collection date is present and is prior to the `postdate`.*

I can't see how to create `meta_query`s which compare a postmeta value with a post value, do I need to use a `posts_join` and `posts_where`?

Apologies if I haven't explained this well.

---

**edit**: The following MySQL query fetches the correct posts:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_date, pm.meta_value, pm.meta_key
FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_delivery_date_ymd'
AND pm.meta_value != ''
AND pm.meta_value < p.post_date
```

---

Similar, but unanswered question: [How can I create a WP_Query that returns posts where one meta_value <= another meta_value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211435/how-can-i-create-a-wp-query-that-returns-posts-where-one-meta-value-another-m)

---

*- This occurs when WooCommerce Subscriptions create renewal orders and the postmeta is copied verbatim.

Comment: Do you need this for all post types or for only `shop_order` post type ?

Comment: only `shop_order` (and only when I've checked a checkbox I've added to the filters)

Comment: Checkbox ??? I've understood this checkbox part. And you've not mentioned it in your question.

Comment: The checkbox part isn't really relevant, I only mention it now so that people know that this isn't a permanent filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below solution will work-

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'the_dramatist_filter_shop_order' );
function the_dramatist_filter_shop_order( $query ) {

    if( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && in_array( $query->get('post_type'), array('shop_order') ) ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_join', 'the_dramatist_shop_order_query_join' );
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'the_dramatist_shop_order_filter_date' );
    }
}

function the_dramatist_shop_order_filter_date( $where ){
    global $wpdb;
    $where .= " AND pm.meta_key = '_delivery_date_ymd' AND pm.meta_value != '' AND pm.meta_value < " . $wpdb->prefix ."posts.post_date";
    return $where;
}

function the_dramatist_shop_order_query_join( $join ){
    global $wpdb;
    $join .= ' RIGHT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts.ID ';
    return $join;
}

// remove_filter('posts_join', 'the_dramatist_shop_order_query_join' ); // remove filter because not to effect another query to use after this query.
// remove_filter('posts_where', 'the_dramatist_shop_order_filter_date' ); // remove filter because not to effect another query to use after this query.
```

I've not found any way to remove this filters after `pre_get_posts` query is completed. It's better and best practice to remove those filters after the query is completed. But also it's not that necessary here cause we are only running this query on `shop_order` post type.

Hope that helps.